# Error on uploading a file in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, file-upload

I've deployed an app to the IIS(and it works) and now I need to upload files to it. On Visual Studio I can upload files by running it with the admin role, but once published, it says that: "ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource". 
Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the application pools for .Net Framework associated with the classic or integrated mode. if it is classic mode means, you have to change the integrated mode, then restart the IIS server. After successfully restarted IIS server, you can run the application now.

Step:

1. Go to application deployed folder location in Windows Explorer
2. Right click the main folder or specific folder or file, and then click Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog box, click the Security tab.
4. On the Security tab, you can see the list of users. If the Network Service account or ASP.NET account is not listed, add it.
5. In the Properties dialog box, click the Edit of Network Service or ASP.NET user name, and in the Permissions for NETWORK SERVICE section, select the Read, Write, and Modify permissions.
6. Click Apply, and then click OK.

you can see the screen by screen step following link

http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/permissions.asp

Edit:

Here's the screenshoot.

[image]

Comment: I've checked and it's set to integrated. The application is properly deployed and the only thing that is not working is the file upload.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the error? so I can able to help you

Comment: no. I asked you to give error image content to English. I am not able to read the error message.

Comment: can you check and let me know